# How to structure my own client side functions in meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Having started with meteor.js, I am already using boilerplates to structure my templates, my client and serverside and shared code.

What I do not know yet is:

- Where to save my own Javascript functions, that might be reused?
- How to write the files which contain functions that might be reused, while avoiding name conflicts?

I know there are many ways in Javascript to write a function or a method.

- Simply a function declaration
- An objetc with a function
- A modelation of static functions

Code Snippet for static functions:

```
function MyClass(){}
MyClass.myStaticFunction = function(){};
```

Answer (score 0):

It is important to note that all Javascript files in the `/client` folder will be loaded in by the client. All of the files will be load in depth-first, then alphabetical order. They are also wrapped in a function so that each file will not populate the global scope. If your file has `function a() {}` then `a` is only callable from within the file.

If you instead, change that to `this.a = function() {}`, `a` is callable from any other file that is loaded after this file or has code that runs after initial load.

For JavaScript files that will be reused by the client, I recommend structuring your `/client` folder so that common code gets loaded first, and that you use the `this.functionName = function() {}` style.